Why does "disclaimmer" return a result but not "disclaimer"?
Searching for "disclaimmer" returns a result but not "disclaimer", even though the matched text in the returned post is "disclaiming". Why?
(Ignore results pointing to Why does "disclaimmer" return a result but not "disclaimer"?)

the first now, as probably expected, returns one result, but not the one you're looking for ;)

Looks like it use some "auto fix" that change disclaimmer to disclaiming or disclaimed behind the scenes, perhaps even built-in feature of Elastic Search which they're using. Edit: found it. I'll try to look for more examples and perhaps post answer with that as "best guess", but only developer can confirm.

@KevinB It shows two, for me.

Isn't this just how some search works? If a search for a term that isn't a valid "word" (e.g. the misspelled "disclaimmer"), it returns results with any of several possible "correct" words instead of the exact term, as if the search was for something more like discla*. But "disclaimer" is a word, so it just says there are no results. That said, many search tools will search with "fuzzy" attributes, allowing singular/plural forms, etc.
